# Trying to use a webhook with stripe to send data into a Node.JS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I only need to do a get request with this webhook. Stripe is indeed sending information to the webhook i just cant figure out how to retrieve the information in Node.JS. I know i need to setup a webhook listener to watch for requests however i cannot find any good useful tutorials. I am currently using hook.io as my webhook vendor. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting this answer late, I figured this out awhile ago. If you visit this link and follow it step by step it worked like a charm for me. Just create a new PHP file on your webserver copy and paste the code and make the changes necessary to fit your needs.

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/integration-builder

Answer (score 1):

First thing first (I'm a bit of a purist) Node.js is not a language but a runtime environment. So I'll assume that you're using Express.js as your web framework.

[image: Stripe Dashboard]

Then you'll have to **Add an endpoint**, select the appropriates events, and you'll be good to go. Stripe will **POST** events to your endpoint. You'll be then able to parse the body of the request to handle them.

[image]
*Edit : domain won't be ngrok.io but something like mysubdomain.ngrok.io*

then on your app.js (or any router)

```js
app.post('/my-endpoint', (req, res, next) => {
  // Do whatever you want with req.body
  // Fetching a database, send a email to customer... 

  res.sendStatus(200) 
  // ALWAYS answer 2XX to Stripe otherwise it'll be considered as failed on Stripe's end.
})
```

If you're new to webhook, I highly suggest you to download [**Stripe CLI**](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli), and use [**Ngrok**](https://ngrok.com/) to test webhooks locally before going live. I'm currently writing a dev.to post about Stripe's webhooks, I'll post it once done.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an Express-based example here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/tree/master/examples/webhook-signing/node-express